# Cassandra and <=, => operators on dates without ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm a noobie with cassandra and I dont understand why I cant filtering by dates (wanna return result between date) for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test.service_bar(
    service_bar_id UUID,
    start_date_time timestamp,
    end_date_time timestamp,
    title varchar,
    message text,
    is_active boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY((start_date_time, end_date_time))
);
```

then this work:

```
  SELECT start_date_time, end_date_time, is_active, message, service_bar_id, title
  FROM test.service_bar
  WHERE start_date_time = '2019-10-30 14:10:29'  AND end_date_time = '2019-10-30 14:10:29'
  LIMIT 500;
```

but this dosent

```
  SELECT start_date_time, end_date_time, is_active, message, service_bar_id, title
  FROM test.service_bar
  WHERE start_date_time >= '2019-10-30 14:10:29'  AND end_date_time <= '2019-10-30 14:10:29'
  LIMIT 500;
```

I cant use `ALLOW FILTERING`

how I can do such queries in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont understand why I cant filtering by dates (wanna return result between date)

The behavior you are seeing is because of this:

```
PRIMARY KEY((start_date_time, end_date_time))
```

You have defined `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` as a composite partition key.  As Cassandra uses a distributed hash to ensure proper data distribution, partitions are not stored in order of their values.  They are stored by the *hashed token value* of the partition key.  You can see this by using the `token` function on the partition key:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT token(start_date_time,end_date_time),start_date_time,end_date_time,service_bar_id FROM service_bar ;

 system.token(
     start_date_time,
     end_date_time)   | start_date_time                 | end_date_time                   | service_bar_id
----------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------
    26346508703811310 | 2019-10-30 19:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 19:10:29.000000+0000 | 49a70440-8689-4248-b389-13b8d0373e58
  1488616260313758762 | 2019-11-01 19:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-11-01 19:10:29.000000+0000 | b0bab610-a285-41e7-ba5c-d56f8fb12f52
  2185622653117187064 | 2019-10-30 21:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 21:10:29.000000+0000 | 3686c6a6-fd8d-4247-b501-964363a48f63
  7727638696734890177 | 2019-10-30 20:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 20:10:29.000000+0000 | 97fc799e-fb54-4b7f-956e-f06bcb9e9d9d

(4 rows)
```

That's the default order of your rows.  This is done because each node is responsible for specific token ranges, to ensure that data is distributed as evenly as possible in a multi-node cluster (which is the usual production use case).  Because of this, CQL has some limitations on how you can query partition keys.  These limitations are in-place to save you from writing bad queries...such as not allowing range queries on partition keys.

> how I can do such queries in Cassandra?

This should also tell you, that you should build your tables and queries to ensure that they can be fulfilled by a request to a single node.  Given that, your use case will really only work if you change your partition key.

One way which dev teams implement solutions like yours, is to use a modeling technique called "time bucketing" or sometimes just "bucketing."  In this case, let's say that you'll never write more than a few thousand entries per month.  Maybe that's not the case, but I'll use it for this example.  I can then partition on month, and then use the `_time` columns as clustering keys.

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.service_bar_by_month (
    month_bucket int,
    start_date_time timestamp,
    end_date_time timestamp,
    is_active boolean,
    message text,
    service_bar_id uuid,
    title text,
    PRIMARY KEY (month_bucket, start_date_time, end_date_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start_date_time DESC, end_date_time DESC);
```

This will store all rows together by the value of `month_bucket`, and within each partition, the rows will be sorted by `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` in descending order.  Now this works:

```
aaron@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT start_date_time, end_date_time, is_active, message, service_bar_id, title
                 ... FROM service_bar_by_month
                 ... WHERE month_bucket = 201910 AND start_date_time >= '2019-10-30 14:10:29'  AND start_date_time <= '2019-10-31 23:59:59';

 start_date_time                 | end_date_time                   | is_active | message           | service_bar_id                       | title
---------------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+--------
 2019-10-30 21:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 21:10:29.000000+0000 |      True | This is an alert3 | eae5d3be-b2b2-40a1-aa28-0412fe9c18e6 | alert3
 2019-10-30 20:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 20:10:29.000000+0000 |      True | This is an alert2 | af4ec72f-7758-42ef-b731-8d08f8a00006 | alert2
 2019-10-30 19:10:29.000000+0000 | 2019-10-30 19:10:29.000000+0000 |      True | This is an alert1 | 8b13db5c-9e39-4ee5-90a9-64758c5ab5be | alert1

(3 rows)
```

Do note though, that you can only enforce a range query on a single clustering key, like `start_date_time` above.  This can't work:

```
AND start_date_time >= '2019-10-30 14:10:29'  AND end_date_time <= '2019-10-31 23:59:59';
```

And it can't work because Cassandra is designed to both read and write data from/to disk sequentially.  Allowing range queries on multiple columns in a single query would require Cassandra to do *random* reads, which it just isn't good at.  You can *make* it do that by using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive, but that's not recommended.  Although, using `ALLOW FILTERING` *within* small partitions would probably perform ok.

Comment: Just a small comment concerning the month_bucket in your example: even with only a few thousand entries per month, this would lead to big partitions. Ok in many years, but just for the understanding: there would be only 12 partitions for all entries

Comment: @AlexTbk The year is also a part of the `month_bucket` ex: `201910` for October of 2019; so October of 2020 (`202010`) would be a different bucket (partition).  And like I noted, month was chosen only for the purposes of demonstration.  A more precise time bucket can be used, while trading some query flexibility.